# Convert String to the correct avro type at runtime

Tags: java, kotlin, avro

Considering I know the schema (this is only known at runtime) how can I create/update an avro message to have the correct type? For example:

> ```
>   val builder = GenericRecordBuilder(schema)
>       builder.set("someKey", "SomeValueAsAString")
> ```

If the type for `someKey` is Number (Int in avro) this will fail at encoding. One way I can think about is getting the avro type `schema.getField("someKey").schema().type` map it to to java / kotlin type and convert it, although I am not sure if this willl work properly. Are there any better solutions for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've found there are 2 solutions:

1. you handle the conversion yourself
2. use a library that already does that. I've used https://github.com/allegro/json-avro-converter and converted my GenericRecord to a JSON.

```
val converter = JsonAvroConverter()
converter.convertToGenericDataRecord(decodedMessage.toString().toByteArray(), schema)
```

in my case `decodedMessage` is a `GenericRecord`

Comment: This is a breaking solution for Avro 1.11

Answer (score 0):

Avro doesn't parse from String to your desired type, hence the problem. You are obligated to provide the `set` method with the exact object you want to populate the record field with. I suggest just using a `switch` on the field type for conversion.

You could however look if there is any pre-implemented method that does that. I couldn't find any.